# How to hide/un hide a sheet based on a cell value in another sheet without using macro or vba

Tags: excel

I need to hide some sheets if a cell value in sheet1 is 'N' and unhide if the value is 'Y'. I had to do this with out using macro's or vba. Is there any way to achieve this using formula's.

Comment: You can only HIDE cells values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there no way to do this automatically without using vba